# Need help writing the code for the following optimization

Tags: optimization, matlab

I need to find $X$ for which the following expression is minimized:

$$ \min ||Y - F^{-1}(X)||_2 + ||X||_1 $$

where $Y$ is an array (of length approx 44000, an [audio sample I will be reading](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html) using Matlab's `audioread( )` function) and $F^{-1}$ is the [inverse fast Fourier transform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifft.html) `ifft( )`. Subscripts indicate 2-norm and 1-norm respectively.
Could someone help me going about implementing it using Matlab?

Comment: Please explain more about the restrictions on the entries for $X$ over which the minimization is to be performed.  For example, must $X$ be real values?

Comment: Are you aware that minimizing $\| F(Y) - X \|_{2}$ is equivalent to minimzing $\| Y- F^{-1}(X) \|_{2}$?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Could you point me to a proof of that^ so I get a better understanding of the problem I have?

Comment: @hardmath I want X such that ifft(X) is real. How do I add such a constraint?

Comment: @pyronic look up Parselval's theorem and note that with the conventional notation for the discrete Fourier transform, there is a scaling factor of $1/\sqrt{N}$ between the norm of $Y$ and the norm of $F(Y)$.  Also look up the symmetry properties of the discrete Fourier transform to understand how to limit your solutions to real signals.

Comment: Also look at the "Sparse FFT"

Comment: The short answer is to rewrite the objective function with real array $Z $ instead of ifft(X) and $F(Z)$, the fast Fourier transform of $Z$ instead of $X$.

Comment: That is: $$\min_{\text{real } Z} ||Y-Z||_2 + ||F(Z)||_1$$ should be the objective function.  Even this you might prefer to restate in terms of $W = Z-Y$, using $||W||_2 + ||F(W+Y)||_1$, where $W$ ranges over real arrays the same size as $Y$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BrianBorchers. Could you tell me which library I should use to optimize hardmath's expression above? cvx in matlab doesnt work when I use the function fft()

Comment: Thanks a lot @hardmath. Could you tell me which library I should use to optimize your expression above? cvx in matlab doesnt work when I use the function fft()

Comment: You can turn the fft(z)  into a matrix-vector multiplication by finding the matrix $F$ so that $Fz=\mathrm{fft}(z)$.

Comment: Instead of using CVX you might consider using a solver like TFOCS or SPGL1, both of which can work with linear operators like fft().